# Why does YouTube API take so long to respond?

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I use youtube API to get tags of 1 video in my android project. However, the server's response time is too long (about 30 seconds). Chrome loads the youtube API in just 1 second. I tried using another API on my project and the response time was only about 1 second. Please show me the reason and solution if possible?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=YouTube+API+take+so+long+to+respond

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube API have authentication on the server. that means that it first authenticate API key and then gives the result. i think it takes time. I suggest you use jsoup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try using jsoup. I don't know why loading API with chrome  is so fast but on my android app it has to wait 30 seconds. Hope someone will have the answer.